# OpenSSL: JRuby only supports F_SETFL for fcntl/ioctl currently

Tags: ruby, openssl, jruby

When I attempt to use net/https with JRuby 1.3.0RC1 with the jruby-openssl-0.5.1 gem installed I get the following error:

```
Error in JobsRequiringReportDataProcessor: JRuby only supports F_SETFL for fcntl/ioctl currently
/opt/bin/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/jruby-openssl-0.5.1/lib/openssl/ssl.rb:56:in `initialize'
/opt/bin/jruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:571:in `connect'
/opt/bin/jruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:557:in `do_start'
/opt/bin/jruby/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:546:in `start'
```

Not sure what is causing this so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This should be fixed by upgrading to jruby-openssl 0.5.1.

Answer (score 0):

Or perhaps upgrade to JRuby 1.3.1 ???